# JSPDF is undefined on IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I have page that need to be open in compatibility mode. I have add the JSPDF but it only works if I change to IE9 or above
on IE7 it says JSPDF is undefined. any alternative to PDF a webpage on click of a button `

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function demoFromHTML() {

    alert("a");
      var doc = new jsPDF()

doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10)
doc.save('a4.pdf') }
</script>
<a href="javascript:demoFromHTML()" class="button">PDF</a>
```

Comment: It is very much possible, that this library does not support IE7. If it's undefined just display a message, "You should be using IE9+, Firefox..."

Comment: I need this to work on ie7 or alternative

Comment: Go to this page https://parall.ax/products/jspdf if in IE7 it does not work, you have to search for another library, or request for support extend.

Comment: what's  the alternative

Comment: Something on java plugin or maybe flash should do for IE7, but exactly I have no idea.